# Is this a vector field on the sphere?

Tags: geometry, manifolds

The definition I have of vector field of a manifold $M$ is an application $X:M\to TM$. So for example, if I take the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, the application $f(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$ is not a vector field of the sphere ? (since $f(x,y,z)$ is a normal vector) If not, what is it ?

I'm a bit suprised by it, because for me, if $f(x,y)=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$ is a function $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$, and if $\gamma=\gamma  (t)\in\mathbb R^2$ is a curve of $\mathbb R^2$, then $t\mapsto f(\varphi (t))$ was a vector field on the curve $\gamma $... This is wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "vector field" almost always means "a *tangent*-vector field", i.e., an assignment, to each point $p$ of $M$, of a vector $v(p) \in T_p(M)$.

What you've described could be called a "normal-vector field", I suppose.

As an example of a tangent-vector field, you could define 
$$
f(x, y, z) = \pmatrix{-y\\x\\0}
$$

We sometimes, when we have a curve $\gamma$ in a manifold $M$, refer to a "field along $\gamma$"; in this case, the vector at $\gamma(t)$ must lie in $T_{\gamma(t)} M$. In the example you cited, the space $\Bbb R^2$ is the manifold $M$, and the vector $f(\gamma(t))$ is in fact an element of the tangent space to $\Bbb R^2$ at the point $\gamma(t)$.

How do you know which of these concepts is the one under discussion? To be honest, it's mostly context, although good writers will typically try to make clear what the domain and codomain of all functions are, so you'll have a good hint. The function 
$$
X : [0, 1] \to T \Bbb R^2: t \mapsto f(\gamma(t))
$$
for instance, is a "vector field along $\gamma$" with the vectors being tangent vectors to $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: So, $f(\gamma (t))$ is what ? Is not a vector field on the curve $\gamma $ ?

Comment: See expanded answer.

Comment: So in fact $f(\gamma (t))$ doesn't must be tangent to the curve $\gamma $ but to $M$, is it right ?

Comment: When we speak of "a vector field along a curve", the vectors must be tangent to the manifold $M$ in which the curve lies. If you wrote about a "field of vectors tangent to $\gamma$", I'd expect the vector at $\gamma(a)$ to be a multiple of $\gamma'(a)$.

Comment: By the way, I've never seen the phrase "a vector field ***on*** $\gamma$" used (but perhaps I've just read different books/papers).

Comment: you right, it's written "a vector field along $\gamma $" :-)

Answer (score 1):

The vector has to be tangent to the sphere this means that $<(x,y,z);X(x,y,z)>=0$ where $(x,y,z)\in S^2$, $X(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$ is not tangent to the sphere. But $Y=(-y,x,0)$ is tangent to the sphere.

It is the derivative, $f'(\gamma(t)).\gamma'(t)$ which is tangent to the curve.

Comment: So, $f(\gamma (t))$ is what ? Is not a vector field on the curve $\gamma $ ?

Comment: it is the derivative, $f"(\gamma(t)).\gamma'(t)$ which is tangent to the curve.